# Formulário Reativo Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Quero setar um valor em um FormArray do Angular Reactive Forms e tentei dessa forma:

```
this.formVariable.controls['variables']['value'][id].patchValue({value:"valor"})
```

esse ['variables'] é do tipo FormArray, não consigo mudar o valor de um item dinamicamente.

Comment: `formVariable` é um `FormGroup`, correto? Vc poderia mostrar como vc criou ele pra termos uma ideia melhor? É que do jeito que está eu sei que `formVariable` tem um controle chamado `variables` que é um `FormArray`, mas não sei a estrutura dele, então seria bom mostrar certinho com os tipos certinhos. Adiciona também a versão do Angular.

Comment: @wldomiciano obrigado! Eu consegui resolver ontem com o setValue(), agradeço muito a ajuda!
```
if(data){         this.formVariable.value['variables'][id]['value'] = data;          const newValue = this.formVariable.value['variables'];         this.formVariable.setValue({variables: newValue});       }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A estrutura do meu formVariable é essa:

```
this.fb.group({
      variables: this.setVariable(),
    });
```

Fiz com setValue dessa forma.

`if(data){ this.formVariable.value['variables'][id]['value'] = data; const newValue = this.formVariable.value['variables']; this.formVariable.setValue({variables: newValue}); }`

E quando quis colocar para editar, eu adicionei um:

````
      for(let i=this.formString.value['values'].length; i<this.arrayString.length; i++){
        try{
          this.addString();
        }catch(err){}
      }
    ```
````

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Criei um exemplo simples de como mudar o valor de um formGroup dentro de um formArray com base nas pouca informações fornecidas.
segue abaixo o codigo do exemplo.

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <div>
   {{ formVariable.value | json}}
  </div>

  <button (click)="addItem('variavel')"> novo item </button>

  <div *ngFor="let group of getVariables().controls; let idx = index">

    <button (click)="setValueVariable(idx)"> Mudar valor do item ({{group.value?.name}}) </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
 export class AppComponent {
 title = 'teste';

 public formVariable: FormGroup;

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
   this.formVariable = this.fb.group({
     variables: this.fb.array([])
   })
 }

 getVariables(): FormArray {
   return this.formVariable.get('variables') as FormArray;
 }

 addItem(name: any){

   let value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
   let index = (this.getVariables().controls.length) + 1;
   let variable = this.fb.group({
     value: [value, [Validators.required]],
     name: [name + ' ' + index.toString(), [Validators.required]]
   })

   console.log(variable);
   this.getVariables().push(variable);

 }

 setValueVariable(index: any){
   let value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
   this.getVariables().controls[index].patchValue({value})
 }
}
```

Para mais informaçoes consulte a documentação oficial do angular sobre [`FormArray`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

Comment: Resolvi desse jeito
`if(data){
        this.formVariable.value['variables'][id]['value'] = data;

        const newValue = this.formVariable.value['variables'];
        this.formVariable.setValue({variables: newValue});
      }`

Answer (score -3):

Vi que conseguiu resolver, mas gostaria de mostrar uma outra forma que pode funcionar.

Quando vc muda o valor através da propriedade `value`, vc perde algumas facilidades que o Angular oferece, dependendo da versão, é claro.

Este código eu testei na versão 16.

Veja como usando o método `at` do `FormArray` vc consegue alterar facilmente o valor de seus controles.

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgFor, ReactiveFormsModule],
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formVariable">
      <div formArrayName="variables">
        <div
          *ngFor="
            let item of formVariable.controls.variables.controls;
            index as id
          "
        >
          <input [formControlName]="id" />

          <button (click)="change(id)">Change</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly formVariable = new FormGroup({
    variables: new FormArray([
      new FormControl('Value 0', { nonNullable: true }),
      new FormControl('Value 1', { nonNullable: true }),
    ]),
  });

  change(id: number): void {
    const data = 'NEW VALUE ' + id;

    if (data && id < this.formVariable.controls.variables.length) {
      this.formVariable.controls.variables.at(id).patchValue(data);
    }
  }
}
```